# What is the purpose of an extra datalist tag inside input-list tag?

Tags: html, input, tags, html-lists

Consider the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

There are a variety of input elements for different specific purposes. For having an optional data-list with the text we replace `<input type="text">` with `<input list="value">`. Now when `<input list>` tag is written, it is obvious that we are having a data-list. Then why do we need to mention an extra `<datalist>` tag for encapsulating the option-values? Why haven't all the features of data-list tag been added to input-list tag?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly, but I think the `<datalist>` as you say is needed because you can add parameters like `id=' '`. In that case you can later do things with that certain datalist using JavaScript. e.g. using `getElementId`. Let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: Can't we add the same parameters like `id=" "` to input-list tag? My question is that since `<input list="xyz">` will contain only one data-list, why not add all the required parameters to `<input list="xyz">` tag?

Comment: To be honest I can't find the reason aswell. Creating a separate element for data seems useful, since you can't have another datalist. I would guess that implementing an element like that might become handy in the future. Maybe we won't be restricted to a single datalist some day.. (wondering)